# How to join two pandas Series into a single one with interleaved values?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two pandas.Series...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

length = 5
s1 = pd.Series( [1]*length ) # [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
s2 = pd.Series( [2]*length ) # [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

...and I would like to have them joined together in a single Series with the interleaved values from the first 2 series.
Something like: [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [np.column_stack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html):

```
In[27]:pd.Series(np.column_stack((s1,s2)).flatten())
Out[27]: 
0    1
1    2
2    1
3    2
4    1
5    2
6    1
7    2
8    1
9    2
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 4):

Here we are:

```
s1.index = range(0,len(s1)*2,2)
s2.index = range(1,len(s2)*2,2)
interleaved = pd.concat([s1,s2]).sort_index()

idx  values
0    1
1    2
2    1
3    2
4    1
5    2
6    1
7    2
8    1
9    2
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one using `NumPy stacking`, [`np.vstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) -

```
pd.Series(np.vstack((s1,s2)).ravel('F'))
```

Comment: I have a doubt `flatten` and `ravel` are similar is there a specific difference?

Comment: @shivsn Yeah I think `.flatten()` makes a copy. Not sure if that will cause any efficiency issue here though. Ah just found out that even though `.ravel()` doesn't make a copy, but `.ravel('F')` will. So, I guess in terms of memory efficiency it should be the same.

Comment: Thanks so its better practice to avoid any warnings lot to learn.